# Linking to Fancy Box Inside an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a site going here: http://treethink.treethink.net/
All the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net) iFrames work but if you go the portfolio section then click on one of the links it takes you to a page and closes Fancy Box.

How can I modify Fancy Box so that when one of those links is clicked inside the portfolio iFrame, it stays in the iFrame and goes to the link?

Here are the fancybox files:

http://treethink.treethink.net/wp-content/themes/treethink/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.js

http://treethink.treethink.net/wp-content/themes/treethink/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.css

http://treethink.treethink.net/wp-content/themes/treethink/fancybox/web.js

I previously had a site going at http://treethink.treethink.net/backup before I installed wordpress, maybe there's a way I can alter what I had hear so when a link is clicked, it does the transition and overlay stuff first then loads whatever content was in that link? That might be a better way of going about it, not sure.

Thanks a lot, Wade

Comment: Would an ajax thickbox be best for this? http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: I am trying out thickbox now but having problems making it do a percentage width.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use thickbox and you're having a problem do percentage width / height it's a pretty easy fix. You can auto set the width and height by detecting the window dimensions.

**Example (if you want 90%):**

```
var screenW = $(window).width();
var screenH = $(window).height();
var thickboxW = Math.round(screenW * 0.9);
var thickboxH = Math.round(screenH * 0.9);

// If you want to re-set values if window resized
$(window).resize(function() { 
 /* INSERT ABOVE VARS AND THICKBOX CALL HERE */
});
```